# Problema usando sync_type de cassandra-python-driver

Tags: python, cassandra

Estoy usando [userType](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cqlengine/usertype.html#cassandra.cqlengine.usertype.UserType)  pero obtengo este error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "cassandra-test.py", line 70, in <module>
    sync_type(Image) 
TypeError: sync_type() missing 1 required positional argument: 'type_model'
```

El código que estoy usando es:

```
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from cassandra.cqlengine import connection
from cassandra.cqlengine.management import sync_table, sync_type

class Image(UserType):
    path_to_images = columns.Text()
    images = columns.Map(columns.Text(), columns.Text())

class User(Model):
    __table_name__ = 'auth_user'
    id = columns.TimeUUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    firstName = columns.Text()
    lastName = columns.Text()
    email = columns.Text()
    password = columns.Text()
    images = columns.UserDefinedType(Image)

sync_type(Image)
sync_table(User)
```

Comment: El idioma de este sitio es el español, por favor traduce tu pregunta.

Comment: verdad, no me di cuenta. gracias @toledano

Comment: Hola, ¿cómo estás haciendo la conexión?

Comment: hola @César, la conexión funciona porque estoy dentro del keyspace
y trabajando con otra tablas 

connection.setup(['127.0.0.1'], "cqlengine", protocol_version=3)
cluster = Cluster()
session = cluster.connect('xxxxx')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función [`sync_type`](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cqlengine/management.html?highlight=sync_type#cassandra.cqlengine.management.sync_type) espera que le pases como mínimo dos parámetros:

```
def sync_type(ks_name, type_model, connection=None):
    # ...
```

Por lo tanto, debes ejecutarlo de la siguiente manera (usando el keyspace de tu conexión):

```
sync_type('cqlengine', Image)
```

El problema era que le estabas pasando sólo el tipo.